# KVO or other property observing pattern in unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, navmesh

I am trying to call a function when one of the properties on my object is changed. Other than constantly polling for the property which is inefficient not to mention a hack at best, I can't seem to find a way to do so using C# scripts in Unity 3D.

Specifically, I am using a NavMeshAgent object's isOnOffMeshLink property to decide when to play and stop a specific animation.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: isOnOffMeshLink is a read only property and the animation is to be played during runtime

Comment: You can use C#'s events to do precisely this.